# trash folder seems empty or access denied

Tags: lubuntu, delete, trash

I'm running lubuntu 14.04. Since a while, files I deleted don't show in the trash folder (under pcmanfm as well as under nautilus).
Looking in ~/.local/share, no "trash" folder is visible.
Now I deleted some files in my boot directory in order to gain space for updates, but they oviously are still in the trash folder- no space was gained, not updates con be installed.
Thanks for an advice!

Comment: Are you root user?

Answer (score 1):

If you removed the files as root, then the deleted files will be in `/root/.local/share/Trash`.

The trash file in `~/.local/share` is first created when deleting a files as regular user, so if you haven't done so, it's perfectly normal that you can find it.

Comment: In order to delete files from /boot, I had to be locked in as root user.
Now I have been looking in /root, but no ".local" folder finds there.
When opening pcman fm from terminal as root, I get the following message:   
** (pcmanfm:3845): WARNING **: terminal lxsession-default-terminal isn't known, consider report it to LibFM developers

** (pcmanfm:3845): WARNING **: modules directory is not accessible

(pcmanfm:3845): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 368 was not found when attempting to remove it
Maybe that hat something to do with my problem.

Comment: @user271850 which means that the files deleted are in `/root/.local/share/Trash`

Comment: @user271850 best to report it as a bug to LXDE devs: https://launchpad.net/~lxde/+archive/ubuntu/ppa